# How to return a None if all components are also None, otherwise Some

Tags: scala

I have a case class like:

```
case class Part1(id: Int)
case class Part2(id: Int)
case class Part3(id: Int)
```

The above are all included in the below Parts class:

```
case class Parts(part1: Option[Part1], part2: Option[Part2], part3: Option[Part3])
```

Now currently in my code I have:

```
case (maybePart1, maybePart2, maybePart3) => 
  Parts(maybePart1, maybePart2, maybePart3)
```

But what I really want to do is return None if all of them are None, otherwise return what I am doing above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add another case statement for the case if they are all `None`:

```
case (None, None, None) => None
case (maybePart1, maybePart2, maybePart3) => 
  Some(Parts(maybePart1, maybePart2, maybePart3))
```